# Naming files using macro from mail merge

Tags: vba, mailmerge

I am trying to create a macro to do a mail merge in word 2010 and then split it into different documents.

However, I am stuck at naming the files.
What I am trying to do is copy the very first line from the merged file and then saving it as a string and using that to create a filename. But I am getting a permission error at this point.
below is the macro. Any help on this matter is highly appreciated

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim filname As String


For i = 1 To (ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount)



With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
        .LastRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
    End With
    .Execute Pause:=False
End With

 Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdScreen, Count:=1
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Copy
filname = Selection

ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\New folder\(Desired filename)" & filname & ".docx", FileFormat:= _
    wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles _
    :=True

ActiveWindow.Close

ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord


Next i


End Sub
```